# Eclipse's Color Theme Issue

Tags: eclipse, plugins, colors, themes

Here's my problem: I want to install the Eclipse's Color Theme plugin, but when I go to the MarketPlace and click install, this pop-up message appears.

[It says: "No repository found at http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update." (You should be able to look at it by clicking on this link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjDXY.png)

I'm not sure if it is a matter of my VPN, but I tried to disable it and try again, but it didn't work. I also tried to install it manually with the zip archive, but had no success.

I would really appreciate it if you can give me a hand to finally get it installed.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: That URL returns a 404. Either the Marketplace entry is out of date or incorrect, or the project is dead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The update site has moved to [`https://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/`](https://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/), but the [Eclipse Marketplace entry](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme) still points to the old location.

Use ***Help > Install New Software*** and work with udate site URL [**`https://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/`**](https://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/) instead.

For details see [Eclipse Color Theme issue #281](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme/issues/281)

Comment: Still not fixed, we're in 2022 now.

Comment: @nlhnt Welcome in 2022. What exactly did you do in order that it gets fixed?

Comment: Well I can't fix it cause I am not the uploader, of the package.
I don't know if the authors accept PRs ( I didn't try to create one ).
Not sure if you're asking me wether I put any effort into fixing it or if I managed to fix it?
I applied what you suggested and it works.

Comment: There is nothing to be fixed. The solution is detailed and still works in 2022